# Tradingview plotting on oscillator

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to plot a circle on the oscillator at the event of a crossover.
My goal is to put it where the crossover happened on the oscillator.
Using location.bottom/top puts it at the bottom/top while location.absolute doesn't put it anywhere.
PLEASE HELP:(

This is the code and a screenshot (Orange circle is where it SHOULD be):

valBottom = crossover(val, valSMA) and val < 0

plotshape(valBottom ? high / 2 : na, style=shape.circle, color=green, location=location.bottom, size=size.small)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KZk2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
plot(val, color = valBottom ? color.green : #00000000, linewidth = 5, style = plot.style_circles)
```

You can use a `var float` declared variable to store the crossover, when the next crossover occurs you can compare the two :

```
var float lastCross = na

if valBottom
    if na(lastCross)
        lastCross := val
    else if val > lastCross
        alert(message = "Higher Cross", freq = alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
        lastCross := val
    else
        lastCross := val
```

Comment: and how would I turn this event into an integer to be able to compare them? My goal is to create an alert when the current green dot is > previous green dot. Than you so much  @rumpypumpydumpy